# How to show label of an Edge within a BioGraph

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to draw a biograph in Matlab. I would like to show the names of the nodes and the label of each edge. I am setting the label of a particular edge. And setting the option of the biograph to show the labels of the edges, however it is still not showing them. What am I missing? Is there a way to set the names of the edges through a list? or do you have to do them one by one?

Thank you.

Here is the code:

```
cm = sparse([0 1 1 0 0;1 0 0 1 1;1 0 0 0 0;0 0 0 0 1;1 0 1 0 0]);
names = {'E1','E2','E3','E4','E5'};
bg = biograph(cm,names,'LayoutType','radial','ShowTextInNodes','Label');
bg.nodes(1).Shape = 'circle'; 
bg.nodes(1).Size = [2 2];
bg.nodes(1).color = [.5 .7 1];
bg.edges(1).LineColor =[.5 .7 1];
bg.edges(1).Label = 'labelzz';
bg.edges(1).Description = 'Descriptionzz';
get(bg);
get(bg.edges(1));
gObj = view(bg);
```

And this is the result:

```
Biograph object with 5 nodes and 9 edges.

               ID: ''

            Label: ''

      Description: ''

       LayoutType: 'radial'

      LayoutScale: 1

            Scale: 1

     NodeAutoSize: 'on'

  ShowTextInNodes: 'label'

         EdgeType: 'curved'

    EdgeTextColor: [0 0 0]

       ShowArrows: 'on'

        ArrowSize: 8

      ShowWeights: 'off'

     EdgeFontSize: 8

    NodeCallbacks: @(node)inspect(node)

    EdgeCallbacks: @(edge)inspect(edge)

CustomNodeDrawFcn: []

            Nodes: [5x1 biograph.node]

            Edges: [9x1 biograph.edge]

         ID: 'E1 -> E2'

      Label: 'labelzz'

Description: 'Descriptionzz'

     Weight: 1

  LineWidth: 0.5000

  LineColor: [0.5000 0.7000 1]

   UserData: []
```

Image of the Graph: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n34Rt.png]

Comment: Hi Martin, Thanks for reply. What do you mean by try using 'bg.edges(1).Label = 'labelzz'; - Am I using it in line 8 to define the edge label.

Comment: This appears to be a common problem among users of the bioinformatics toolbox. I found three unanswered questions like yours on Matlab Answers. I think you'll have to contact the author of the toolbox and ask for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Edge Labels or ID cannot be displayed. Only edge weights can be displayed setting the biograph property ShowWeights to 'on'.

Answer (score 1):

Biographs in Matlab only support display numerical weights on the edges, but you can easily modify the code to display arbitrary text.

In the file:
\toolbox\bioinfo\bioinfo\@biograph\@edge\hgUpdate.m

Replace the 2 following lines

```
set(h.hgline,'UserData',text(txy(1),txy(2),[' ' num2str(h.Weight) ' '] ,...
```

and

```
'String',[' ' num2str(h.Weight) ' '],...
```

by

```
set(h.hgline,'UserData',text(txy(1),txy(2),[' ' h.Label ' '] ,...
```

and

```
'String',[' ' h.Label ' '],...
```

Then just set your text in the edges' "Label" property. E.g.

```
graph = biograph([0 1 ; 1 0], {'node1', 'node2'}, 'ShowWeights', 'on');
graph.Edges(1).Label = 'Edge 1-2';
graph.Edges(2).Label = 'Edge 2-1';
view(graph);
```